# Convert Access SQL IIF to T-SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, case

I have someone else's Access query that I need to convert to T-SQL.  I have it mostly done.  These next two lines are my issue.  This is the Access SQL:

```
...
, [MATERIALVALUE]/1000 AS COSTOURS
...
, IIf([ALLJOBS].[SALESID]="SUI",[COSTOURS]=0,IIf([PRICE]=-1,[COSTOURS]=0,[COSTOURS])) AS COST0
...
```

The first line COSTOURS is simple enough.  It is just

```
...
,MATERIALVALUES/1000 COSTOURS
...
```

What I am having problems with is the setting of COSTOURS later in the same SELECT statement's CASE statement as well as what is COST0 getting set to?

My T-SQL case statement is this:

```
    ,CASE AllJobs.SALESID
        WHEN 'SUI' THEN COSTOURS = 0
            ELSE CASE ESSDBtRels.PRICE
                    WHEN -1 THEN COSTOURS = 0
                        ELSE ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE/1000
    END
    END COST0
```

Which doesn't work obviously.  How do I set a previously set column with new results based on a subsequent CASE statement's true attributes.  And what does COST0 get set to in the case of a TRUE and a FALSE, TRUE occasion?  A FALSE, FALSE will set COST0 to COSTOURS.

Thanks @forpas, since MATERIALVALUE has no bearing I will go with the following SQL:

```
        CASE AllJobs.SALESID
        WHEN 'SUI' THEN 0
            ELSE CASE ESSDBtRels.PRICE
                WHEN 1 THEN 0
        ELSE ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE/1000
        END
        END COST0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access a Boolean expression like `[COSTOURS]=0` is evaluated as `-1` for `TRUE` or `0` for `FALSE`.
So to get the same results you should use a CASE statement in the place of these expressions:

```
CASE AllJobs.SALESID
  WHEN 'SUI' THEN CASE ESSDBtRels.[MATERIALVALUE] WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
  ELSE CASE ESSDBtRels.PRICE
    WHEN -1 THEN CASE ESSDBtRels.[MATERIALVALUE] WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
    ELSE ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE/1000
  END
END COST0
```

or with [`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
IIF(
  [ALLJOBS].[SALESID]='SUI',
  IIF(ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE=0, -1, 0),
  IIf(
    [PRICE]=-1,
    IIF(ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE=0, -1, 0),
    ESSDBtRels.MATERIALVALUE/1000
  )
) AS COST0
```

Comment: Oh, so the TRUE parts of each IIF are not actually resetting COSTOURS to 0?

Comment: No they are not.